# How to upload file in dropbox using PHP

Tags: php, html, dropbox

Im beginner in php and I want to learn how to upload file in Dropbox using php. Here is my code.

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';
require 'app/start.php';
require 'app/dropbox_auth.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
        session_start(); 
    }
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


$load = "token/";
$load = $load . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$upload_name = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$client->uploadFile($upload_name,Dropbox\WriteMode::add(),$load);


}
?>
```

and its displaying this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message ''path': bad path: must start with "/": "Blog Topic List.docx"' in D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\lib\Dropbox\Path.php:169 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\lib\Dropbox\Client.php(276): Dropbox\Path::checkArgNonRoot('path', 'Blog Topic List...') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\submit.php(163): Dropbox\Client->uploadFile('Blog Topic List...', Object(Dropbox\WriteMode), 'token/Blog Topi...') #2 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\lib\Dropbox\Path.php on line 169
```

Theres an error on my code

Answer (score 0):

The "path" parameter must be started with /

On last line, change to

```
$client->uploadFile("/" . $upload_name,Dropbox\WriteMode::add(),$load);
```

Ref: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/php

Comment: I already did that then the output is this "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message ''inStream' has bad type; expecting resource, got string' in D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\lib\Dropbox\Checker.php:22 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\lib\Dropbox\Checker.php(27): Dropbox\Checker::throwError('inStream'.......". Sorry If I ask a lot.

Comment: Can you post the full error messages? I suspect the path is incomplete.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message ''inStream' has bad type; expecting resource, got string' in D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\lib\Dropbox\Checker.php:22 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\lib\Dropbox\Checker.php(27):

Comment: Dropbox\Checker::throwError('inStream', 'token/EL NIDO, ...', 'resource') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\lib\Dropbox\Client.php(278): Dropbox\Checker::argResource('inStream', 'token/EL NIDO, ...') #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\submit.php(160): Dropbox\Client->uploadFile('/EL NIDO, PALAW...', Object(Dropbox\WriteMode), 'token/EL NIDO, ...') #3 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\form2\lib\Dropbox\Checker.php on line 22

Comment: Seems the error is from `$load`. You can check the link I provided.